# Missing DLL in Release but not in Debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I am porting an old MFC application from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2019.

In the process, an old DLL library has been incorporated into the source code to remove the library building step in development.

Now, this program runs and functions perfectly when debugging in the default Debug configuration; however, in the Release configuration I get:

> The code execution cannot proceed because `MSVCR90.dll` was not found

I imagine this means that `MSVCR90d.dll` is successfully found in Debug mode, but cannot find the release version of the DLL for some reason.

I've tried all the general steps of downloading Visual C++ Runtime redistributables, changing to statically linked runtime libraries, and most other things found in the first results on Google.

All intermediate versions of Visual Studio are installed locally on the development machine (2008, 2010, 2015, 2017, and 2019).

Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Find whatever part of your old code is referencing that DLL and remove the reference. Newer VS versions, using newer versions of the compiler, should use the appropriately matching runtime DLLs.

Comment: Use procmon.exe on startup. Find out where the loader is looking for files. Find out which file it is failing to load if any besides msvcr90.dll. Verify msvcr90.dll is really there somewhere on your path.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Why would this issue only appear in the Release version? As far as I can tell, I've removed almost all outdated calls/references.

Comment: @satazero 1) Visual studio has different settings for each configuration. So maybe you removed linking against those libraries from the Debug settings, but not from Release. 2) `#ifdef DEBUG ... #endif` is a construct, that is sometimes used (and its `#ifndef DEBUG` counterpart).

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson Doing this and dropping it into the folder it checks C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ just gives me error R6034 Attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly.

Comment: Your program is 32-bits or 64-bits? All the bitness match up? Is your debug and release builds both built for the same bitness ? (32 or 64)

Comment: All of these projects are targeting Win32.

Comment: Are you certain the debug build hadn't been linked *statically* against the old MSVC90d runtime?

That used to (and still is) a common workaround to get debug build portable without requiring the consumer to have the same development environment installed. Albeit at the cost of file size, and a whole bunch of other compatibility issues....

Comment: All the speculation can be avoided, if you install Dependency Walker https://www.dependencywalker.com and see exactly what is missing where and what the differences of the release and the debug builds are.

Comment: @thomiel This pointed out an obvious error. There was a DLL that was still being statically linked in the `Release` config that had now been integrated into the actual source code. Thanks so much, please post an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: @satazero Ok, I added the comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the speculation can be avoided, if you install Dependency Walker https://dependencywalker.com and see exactly what is missing where and what the differences of the release and the debug builds are.